# Laravel 5.3 - Controller store method for this form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a 4 Models

User - basic Laravel user with default fields

Excursion - with fields ['id', 'user_id', 'name', 'start_time', 'end_time']

Bus - with fields ['id', 'excursion_id', 'staff_id', 'staff_qnty', 'staff_price']

Staff - with fields ['id', 'name']

And these are the relations

```
User hasMany Excursion
Excursion belongsTo User

Excursion hasMany Bus
Bus belongsTo Excursion

Bus hasMany Staff
Staff hasMany Bus
```

and i have a pivot table for bus_staff
This is the form for a user:

[image]

And when the user submits the form this is the dd($request);

[image]

How should the MyController@store method look like...
is there a way to save this data with associate() or something? Please help.

Comment: In your input, there is no staff name.

Comment: i fixed it...now there is stuff_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as:

```
$excursion_input = ['name' => $request->get('name'), 'start_time' => $request->get('start'), 'end_time' => $request->get('end')];

$excursion = auth()->user()->excursion()->create($excursion_input);

for ($i=0; $i < count($request->get('stuff_id')); $i++)
{
    $input = [
        'staff_id' => $request->get('stuff_id')[$i],
        'staff_qnty' => $request->get('qnty')[$i],
        'staff_price' => $request->get('price')[$i],
    ];
    $bus = $excursion->bus()->create($input);
}
```

Comment: this would probably work but it is too much code...there must be a way to do it with associate method and sync. The Laravel way!!!

Comment: Your `input` data is not in correct format so we have to `for` loop and `associate()` is used for `belongsTo` relation and `sync()` is used with `belongsToMany`. None of them we are using here to create the model.